# Reversing the string in C

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<malloc.h>
char *str_rev(char s[]){
 static char *st = NULL;
 static char *l;
 int i = 0,c = 0;
 st = malloc((strlen(s) * sizeof(*s))+1);
 *l = st;
 if(s == NULL){
  return "INVALID PARAMS";
 }
 for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
 ;
 }
 for(c=i;c >=0;c--){
  *l++ = s[c];
 }
 l = '\0';

 return st;
}
int main(){
 char a[]="Angus Declan R";
 printf("\n %s \n",str_rev(a));
 return 0;
}
```

How to free the memory allocated using malloc() in the func str_rev() as i need to retrun the reversed string.

Comment: Is this your real code? It doesn't compile.

Comment: Please improve your question with a problem statement and a few sentences explaining your solution approach.

Comment: @nm : yes,this is my real code. Its compiling, but the string is not getting printed in the reverse order.

Comment: What compiler are you using? The code is not valid C, it is missing semicolons in two places.

Comment: http://gnu.org/software/indent

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**(1):** First memory in `l` is `\0` due to following reason that is the reason print nothing:

After your loop

```
for(i=0;s[i]!='\0';i++){
 ;
 }
```

`s[i]` become  `\0` and you assign `c=i` and in second loop  following you are assigning `\0` at first point in `l`.

```
for(c=i;c >=0;c--){
  *l++ = s[c];  // you are assigning `\0` for first time
 }
```

You returns `return l;` and at first position in `l` `\0` is so 
So in printf statement with `%s`

```
printf("\n %s \n",str_rev(a));
```

print nothing.

**Suggestion:**

```
for(c=i-1;c >=0;c--){
     // ^ c should be i-1 initially 
  *l++ = s[c];
 }
```

**(2):** You have two compilation error in question code at-lest. You forgot `;` on two positions

```
 return "INVALID PARAMS"; 
                        ^
```

next

```
char a[]="Angus Declan R";
                         ^
```

**Third Serious mistake**

You are returning an invalid memory address!
what you are doing, allocate memory in `st` , then assign to `l`, then `free(st)` and return `l`: (*read comments*)

```
st = malloc((strlen(s) * sizeof(*s))+1);   // allocation 
l = st;          // assign to l

// code in between

free(st);    // st and l become invalid after free
return l;    // returning invalid memory
```

**Suggestion:**  Do you algo work with `l` and return `st` without calling free().

**(4)**:

This is not error, But why this useless loop ?

```
while(c > 0){
  l--;
  c--;
 }
```

**(5)**: Forgot * in front of `l`

```
for(c=i;c >=0;c--){
  *l++ = s[c];
 }
  l = '\0';
 ^ forgot *   it should be *l = '\0';
```

Comment: You are correct. Sorry I have typo errors as i could not copy and paste it from VMWare, so i note it in a notepad and copied it into here.

Comment: @Angus Its not correct. You should try enough hard before posting a question. ..Please let me know if you have any doubt.

Comment: I have introduced memory cloberring.

Comment: @Angus No problem get ready again try again I have given enough point I think you can rectify your code.

Comment: Thanks. You give hope to improve the coding rather than blaming for the poor coding. I will improve my coding from my next post.

Comment: @Angus Yes its not a big deal. I just passed with C-grad in my college. You just need to read a book + solve each exercise given at back of  every chapter. its only 7 day task

Comment: @Angus Read my answer again I made some changes [**See here is your code on codepad**](http://codepad.org/xMOw5MqA) With all comments. You made only mistakes that can be easily improve. Algo-wise No problem indeed.

Comment: @Angus Are you happy now**?** understood what was the problem?

Comment: Yeah :) . I understood what was the problem.